# Navigate to specific page using Route in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I want to display a page using the routing provided by Angular, in my Routing file if the minType = mino it is necessary to go to another component the one declared in the Routing is it possible?

Do I need to use Childs route? or do an **if()** in the ts file maybe?

thank you.

**Routing**

```
const minRoutes: Routes = [
 {
  path: min/:id/:mineType,
  component: MinComponent,
 }
]
```

**ts.file**

```
getDataFromRoute() {
 this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params:Params) => {
  this.id = params.get('id');
  this.type = params.get('mineType');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this Route:

```
const minRoutes: Routes = [
 {
  path: min/mino/:id,
  component: AnotherComponent,
 },
 {
  path: min/:mineType/:id,
  component: MinComponent,
 }
]
```

Comment: You should explain that the order is what makes this possible